# How to send an http post in ionic2 (typescript) with parameters as a multipart/form-data request?

Tags: php, web-services, typescript, post, ionic2

I have a webservice (Actually generated with the drupal 7 plugin Service) accepting requests on 'http://mywebsite:8080/api_name/user' and checking possible connections against an 'api-key' variable in the requests, containing sort of a password.

Trying to connect to the service with my ionic2/cordova app result in a fail for the payload of the request results empty on the server side ($_REQUEST is an empty array and does not contain the api-key required, so that the request fails).

Debugging the request with https://requestb.in/ shows that the variable is in the body of the request, as expected.

The webservice is working well, on its side, for a post request sent by Google Postman go on successfully (thought I noticed a difference sending the postman request to requestb.in: 'api-key' parameter is not in the body, but in a part called "Form/Post Parameters" and the Content type is 'multipart/form-data' instead of application/json)

I am a bit confused about how my code (that seems correct) is not working...

Here is the code of the function trying to connect to the webservice:

```
register(username,password,email){ 
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      let postParams = {
        "api-key" : "someSecret",
        "name" : "something",
        "mail" : "somethingelse"
      }

      this.http.post("http://mywebsite:8080/api_name/user", postParams, options).subscribe(data => {
          console.log("ok");
        }, error => {
          console.log("error:"+error);// Error getting the data
      });
}
```

EDIT: i'm reading that "$_REQUEST is used to collect data after submitting an HTML form" so the problem lays actually in sending the request as a 'multipart/form-data' but how I can do that? Changing the 'Content-type' in the header seems not to be enough. I tried adding this (with no fortune)

```
headers.append('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of attempts, here it is the correct code:

```
register(username,password,email){ 
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      let postParams:FormData = new FormData();
      postParams.append("api-key", "something secret");

      this.http.post("http://mywebsite:8080/api_name/user", postParams, options).subscribe(data => {
          console.log("ok");
        }, error => {
          console.log("error:"+error); // Error getting the data
      });
}
```